# @szhsin/react-menu can't get Menu items inline, always one on top of another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, menu

I'm trying to get the Menu (from @szhsin/react-menu module) element buttons to show up to the right of the previous generated item, however I'm a bit lost as to how to get it to do so. Everything results in the element showing below previous.

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Menu,
    MenuItem,
    MenuButton,
    SubMenu
} from '@szhsin/react-menu';
import '@szhsin/react-menu/dist/index.css'

class TopMenuDropdown extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.TMPMenuTestCategory.map (({name,items},i) =>
                    {
                    return <Menu
                        align={'end'}
                        key={i}
                        menuButton={<MenuButton>{name}</MenuButton>}
                        reposition={'initial'}
                        >
                        {items.map((item,j) =>
                            {
                                console.log(item,j);
                            return <MenuItem key={j}>{item}</MenuItem>
                            }
                        )}
                    </Menu>
                } )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I was looking through the documentation on https://szhsin.github.io/react-menu/docs , however, me trying the following has had no effect:

Assigning the display:'inline' or 'flex' the `<Menu>` or to a `<div><Menu>` as I attempted to give each menu it's own div when generated.

Wrapping each generated menu in a `<span>`

Fiddling with the Menu item's props like 'align' , 'position' , and 'reposition' (though I'm guessing Reposition needs an additional RepositionFlag to work if I understand it correctly)

Here's the snippet of index.JS it is part of

```
const basicMenuArray = [
    { name: 'ProTIS', items: [ 'Login', 'Exit' ] },
    { name: 'Project', items: [ 'Open', 'Info' ] },
]

class App extends React.Component {
    state={
        language:'sq'
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div >
                <div style={{display:'flex', width:'75%', float:'left' }}>
                    <span> Temp Text </span>
                </div>
                <div style={{display:'flex', width:'25%'}}>
                    <span style={{marginLeft:'auto'}}>
                        <DataComboBox
                        dropdownOptions={languages}
                        value={this.state.language}
                        valueField='language_code'
                        textField='language_full_name'
                        onChange={(value) => alert(JSON.stringify(value))}
                        />
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <TopMenuDropdown TMPMenuTestCategory={basicMenuArray} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up realizing something this morning, as I'm learning ReactJS still, and my brain did not process the things properly.
I changed the initial

`<div>`

to

```
<div style={{display:'flex'}}>
```

and added a `style={{display:'flex', float:'left'}}` to the `<Menu>` which generates the button.

the final code snippet looks like this for anyone still learning like I am :)

```
 return (
            <div style={{display:'flex'}}>
                {this.props.TMPMenuTestCategory.map (({name,items},i) =>
                    {
                    return <Menu
                        style={{display:'flex', float:'left'}}
                        key={i}
                        menuButton={<MenuButton>{name}</MenuButton>}
                        >
                        {items.map((item,j) =>
                            {
                                console.log(item,j);
                            return <MenuItem key={j}>{item}</MenuItem>
                            }
                        )}
                    </Menu>
                } )}
            </div>
        )
```